# dbinom for Bernoulli trials

Tags: r, self-study, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

I have this question:

"There are a **100** families each with **5** children. Given that the null probability of having a boy is $p=0.5$, what is the probability of a family having **0,1,2,3,4,5** boys"

We have been asked specifically to use **dbinom** from R.

My solution:

> dbinom(0:5,5,0.5)

```
0.03125

0.15625 

0.31250 

0.31250 

0.15625 

0.03125
```

My question:

Why are the numbers similar, as in why is the probability of having 0 boys the same as 5 boys, or why the probability of having 2 boys the same as having 3 boys?

Comment: Try writing out the math involved, i.e., the formula for the binomial distribution with $p = 0.5$ and $n = 5$, and it will become clear.

Comment: Hint: when there are two boys how many girls are there?

Comment: Shouldn't the probability of 3 girls and 2 boys be the same as having 3 boys and 2 girls since p=0.50

Comment: The results show a symmetry which should be the case when p=0.50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Binomial coefficients have a symmetry which can be seen from their formula or visually from their relationship to [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), as seen in this image from the wikipedia page:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Pascal_triangle_small.png]

Note that the dbinom output is just a normalised representation of the relevant row from Pascal's Triangle:

```
prop.table(c(1,5,10,10,5,1))
[1] 0.03125 0.15625 0.31250 0.31250 0.15625 0.03125
```